# Can I run a sub in a VBA userform if something is triple clicked? (or more clicks)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I was wondering if I can run a sub/macro when something within my userform is tripleclicked(or more clicks)? Whereas "something" could be a label, image, textbox or whatever.

Basically using this method:

```
Private Sub UserForm_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
End Sub
```

But for a triple click?

I had no luck when searching the web for such information.

Comment: A "triple" click or more is not a convention. Seeing how people even have problems performing double and single clicks without faults, basing an action on a triple click does not look like a reliable user input method.

Comment: I do not disagree with you. 
But it is intended to be used as a easter egg for someone who clicks on something more times than they are supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it is intended to be used as a easter egg for someone who clicks on something more times than they are supposed to do. – Nick 1 hour ago

Interesting :) For this you will have to use `_Click()`, `_DblClick()` and a `Application.OnTime`.

**LOGIC:**

1. Start timer in click event `_Click()`, `_DblClick()` if timer is not ON using `Application.OnTime`.
2. Automatically stop timer after 1 second.
3. Check for 3 clicks within 1 second.

**CODE:**

Is this what you are trying?

Paste this in the userform

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    ClicksCount
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    ClicksCount
End Sub

Private Sub ClicksCount()
    If TimerOn = False Then StartTimer

    '~~> Check for the first click
    If StartTick = 0 Then
        StartTick = GetTickCount
        ClickCount = ClickCount + 1
    Else
        EndTick = GetTickCount
        ClickCount = ClickCount + 1
    End If

    If ClickCount > 2 Then
        MsgBox "Triple clicked"
        StartTick = 0: EndTick = 0: ClickCount = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Paste this in a module

```
Option Explicit

Public StartTick As Long, EndTick As Long, ClickCount As Long
Public TimerOn As Boolean
    
Sub StartTimer()
    StartTick = 0: EndTick = 0: ClickCount = 0: TimerOn = True
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"), "StopTimer"
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    StartTick = 0: EndTick = 0: ClickCount = 0: TimerOn = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, It is working, but I do have my reservations. 
This is more complicated than my knowledge so I could definitely not do it better. But, it is working as intended but not with a 100% reliability. Sometimes my "cursor" changes to "something loading" or similar for just a millisecond, but enough to notice. Despite above comments, it is good enough! 
Thank you very much @siddhartrout

Comment: Yes that is because of `Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"), "StopTimer"` :)